# adodb updateBatch storing incorrect info

Tags: vb6, adodb

I have a VB6 program using adodb recordsets an a Microsoft Access 2007 database file; I added code to the application that takes each record in a table, and for most records in the table, I take one field, calculate a new value based on the value in that field, and store that value in another field in the same record.  I tested this and have put it in production; it is running without (reported) error on a large number of laptops.

I got an error reported today; as near as I can tell, the updateBatch method on the record set is storing a slightly different value than the one I put there, certainly different from the one I meant to put there.  I've put it in the debugger and verified that the new value is the one that I want; I have put in statements that write the base value and the new value to a file and verified that THOSE are what I want, and yet different values end up in the database.

Here is the relevant loop:

```
sqlStr = "Select key_citation, long_citeIndex from citation"
Set rs = m_dbh.runSQLReturnRS_RW(sqlStr)
While Not rs.EOF
    citationNumber = rs.Fields("key_citation").value
    If Left$(citationNumber, 1) <> "W" Then
        newIndex = Citation.calculateCiteIndex(citationNumber)
        Open "c:\CitationIndexDebug.txt" For Append As #4
        Write #4, citationNumber, newIndex
        Close #4
        rs.Fields("long_citeIndex").value = newIndex
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Wend
rs.UpdateBatch
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

runSQL etc. opens the recordset with adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic

I've tried putting rs.Update in for each record, but that doesn't seem to work at all; I presume that, because the rest of the app uses updateBatch, that the runSQL statements open the recordsets assuming batch update.

Anyone have any ideas why this would be wrong, and wrong only a small percentage of the time?  As I say, it is running correctly as near as I can tell on scores/hundreds of machines, and then has an error on this particular database.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem consistently in your development environment? If so I would suggest running SQL profiler on the database being updated so that you can see what SQL commands are being generated by ADODB.

Comment: Yes, I can produce the problem repeatedly.  I am not familiar with SQL profiler; can you point me to something that will tell me how to run it?  This is an MS Access database, strictly desktop; I have MS Access but am not running SQL Server at all.  thanks!

Comment: Oops, sorry! I saw that you put Access but for some reason I just assumed SQL server. My comment isn't of much use to you then. Take a look at this question/answer for something similar that might work for you though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735412/access-mdb-is-it-possible-to-monitor-and-log-actual-queries-made-against-an-acc

Comment: Well, I've found out part of the answer.  The loop is meant to skip records where the first character is "W" in the base string; this database has 7 such records.  I wrote trace code to tell me in what order these things are processed, and discovered that the calculated values are off by 6 records.  It appears that moveNext moved the record used for calculating by one, but when storing the calculated value, it stored them in the last record I hadn't written to.

If anyone has any insight on that, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

In what way is the value slightly different than what you are intending to save? Can you provide a few examples of what it is supposed to be and what it is actually saving as?

Comment: I have a field with a 7-character string that contains 6 digits and an "E".  I am calculating a number composed of "1", the position of the "E" in the field, and then the 6 digits in original order.  6866E40 is supposed to result in 15686640, and the calc routine does that correctly, but what's getting stored is 16886621.

Comment: So, when you are testing this specific one, you can step through the code and see that is is setting the long_citeIndex field to the correct value, but then the database is showing the wrong value? Did you have to do anything special to reproduce the problem? Also, does it have the same problems if you use adOpenKeyset or maybe adOpenStatic? I ask because the documentation here: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675283(v=vs.85).aspx) states that they should be used.

Comment: I copied the routine that was running the SQL, modified the copy to use adOpenStatic, and re-ran the test with the same results.

Comment: Yes, I can step through the code, but there are 1700 records in this table and I don't want to step through them all.  I wrote code to write out to a file the base number and the calculated number for each one, and they're as expected.  So they're right when they get calculated and wrong in the database.

Comment: What happens if you switch from using the UpdateBatch command to using Update inside your loop?

Comment: I did try using Update -- I couldn't get it to work, possibly because I don't know much about Update.  I inherited this code and it uses UpdateBatch exclusively.  Please see my partial answer in my comments to the original question, in case using Update will help me solve things now that I've found part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could retrieve the recordset with adOpenForwardOnly, and then send UPDATE SQL statements.  I've invented **m_conn**, but it should be an ADO.Connection object.

```
 sqlStr = "SELECT key_citation FROM citation"
 Set rs = m_conn.Execute(sqlStr, , adCmdText Or adOpenForwardOnly)
 While Not rs.EOF
     citationNumber = rs.Fields(0).Value
     If Left$(citationNumber, 1) <> "W" Then
         newIndex = Citation.calculateCiteIndex(citationNumber)
         m_conn.Execute "UPDATE citation SET long_citeIndex = " & CStr(newIndex) & " WHERE key_citation = " & CStr(citationNumber), , adCmdText
     End If
     rs.MoveNext
 Wend rs.UpdateBatch
 rs.Close
 Set rs = Nothing
```