# how to get sql query in MS Access 2007

Tags: c#, sql, profiling, ms-access-2007

I am using MS Access 2007 database for an application. I want to fetch the query to be executed at run time.

Is there any tool for MS Access 2007 like SQL Profile?

Comment: Debug your application? Put logging methods within the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to find any such tool (i did lots of google few days back, when i was having similar requirements) and finally endup doing import of ms-access db in sql server and change connection, did my work and then changed the connection back to ms-access.. :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do it. but not as like sql profiles. Have you tried turning on the ODBC trace function? Use the ODBC Data Sources control panel applet. Switch to the 'Trace' tab and review the options available.

Here i have found similar with your question.

[Is it possible to monitor and log actual queries made against an Access MDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735412/access-mdb-is-it-possible-to-monitor-and-log-actual-queries-made-against-an-acc)

[Use Microsoft Jet's ShowPlan to write more efficient queries](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-microsoft-jets-showplan-to-write-more-efficient-queries/5064388)