# Access Inner Join Query Result Lagging and Hanging

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have a really simple access join query that makes the whole access lag till the point it is unusable after it has finished running (it takes 5-10s to respond to a mouse scroll, and clicking the "last record" button will cause access to hang). I have two tables, the first having 162768 records and the second having 164984 records. I do an inner join on a field called ACCTNO and only return the ACCTNO from both tables:

```
SELECT [First_Table].[AcctNo(D)], [Second_Table].[AcctNo(D)]
FROM [First_Table] INNER JOIN [Second_Table] ON [First_Table].[AcctNo(D)] = [Second_Table].[AcctNo(D)];
```

I'm not sure if the number of records is an issue, but I've done joins on other tables with over 1 million records. Sure the query takes very long to run but after I get the results everything works just fine. What might be the issue here. Thanks.

Comment: Are both of those fields indexed?

Comment: Nope I did not index any fields. Somehow I got it to work properly. I created a Distinct query of both the original tables, and query upon those queries instead and it does not lag or hang anymore.

The weird thing is even after applying Distinct the number of records in the original tables remain the same, so I have absolutely no idea what is happening here.

Comment: @JustinLeo that's what Gord was trying to say: if the fields are not indexed, you'll always get poor performance on joins because the database engine will need to do table scans which are very costly. Always keep indexes for your primary and foreign keys as a minimum. Use [Showplan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735412/access-mdb-is-it-possible-to-monitor-and-log-actual-queries-made-against-an-acc) to help you find out how your queries are handled by the database engine.