# Extract SQL statement text from DAO recordset object?

Tags: sql, vb6, dao, recordset

Once a recordset object is created & configured, is it possible to **extract the text of the equivalent SQL statement** that it will generate?

In my specific case I have an older VB6 application which uses DAO360 for MDB database operations.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```vb
sqlText = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE 1 = 2"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sqlText, dbOpenTable)

rs.AddNew
rs("item1").Value = "value1"
rs("item2").Value = "value2"
rs("item3").Value = "value3"

'----- Ideally extract the SQL statement at this line -----
rs.Update
```

In my current problem the `Update` call produces a SQL processing error and I'm trying to identify the cause. Having the actual SQL statement might be useful.

Comment: No, its not exposed anywhere. I remember using JETSHOWPLAN which can output some query metrics, here is a related question with a lot of dead links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735412/is-it-possible-to-monitor-and-log-actual-queries-made-against-an-access-mdb.  By *Access error* do you mean a crash-to-desktop access violation or an error from the Access application?

Comment: @AlexK. the error I referred to was the latter - a SQL processing error, not an actual Access process crash. I'll clarify this in the question thanks.